# How to get inline error checking working with Atom/Nuclide and Hack?

Tags: ubuntu, atom-editor, hacklang, nuclide-editor

Nuclide supposedly [supports error checking](http://nuclide.io/docs/hack/), but I can't figure out how to set it up.

- I have a fresh install of Atom
- I installed Nuclide via `apm install nuclide-installer`
- I've verified Hack is installed correctly by running `hh_client` from my project dir on the commandline and it does report errors
- I have an `.hhconfig` in my project root, but it's empty (no idea what to put inside it)
- Watchman is installed

No errors are displayed in the IDE (see screenshot). Is there something else I have to do?

[image: hack screenshot]

```
$ atom --version
1.0.11
$ hh_client
hacktest.php:4:10,21: Invalid return type (Typing[4110])
  hacktest.php:3:22,24: This is an int
  hacktest.php:4:10,21: It is incompatible with a string
hacktest.php:9:1,0: Expected ; (Parsing[1002])
$ watchman --version
3.7.0
$ stat .hhconfig
  File: ‘.hhconfig’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that's an installer issue (we had experienced a similar incident), so the `hack` package isn't properly installed/activated. Could you try building Nuclide from source and see it that fixes the issue for you: https://github.com/facebook/nuclide#building-from-source

Comment: I deleted all my packages and then installed from source like you suggested. It installed 36 packages. There's still no error checking.

Comment: You are on the right track, we just happen to currently have an issue that will be fixed with the next push - verify from Atom dev tool console error, cmd+shift+i.

Comment: "Failed to require the main module of 'nuclide-debugger-node' because it requires an incompatible native module.
Run `apm rebuild` in the package directory to resolve.". Rebuild says "Unsupported target version: 0.22.0".

Comment: this has also been fixed by excluding it from the release and will be pushed with the next push.